# Effective versioning of Components in Jira/GreenHopper?

Tags: jira, agile, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, jira-agile

Is there a best practise or recommended method of versioning components of a project? Just I may have an **EnvironmentServices** project with components *SpecificService1*, *SpecificService2*... each of these children have independent versioning.

What is the most effective method of implementing this? As standalone Jira doesn't seem to support component versioning: [as raised here.](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-3501)

Would it be to create projects for each '*SpecificService*' I wish to have a lifecyle for? Or can I take advantage of GreenHopper and use Component/Version hierarchies?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have this as our company, and after trying the Greenhopper stuff, we went back to the obvious answer: naming conventions.

As an example, say we have a single project for some tightly integrated codebases which include REST Service and an administration WebApp.  We then have the components "Service" and "WebApp".  Then we create versions called "Service 1.2.0" and "WebApp 2.1.1".  This allows us to have bugs which apply to both components to be in both versions.

It doesn't enforce anything, but it is really clear to anyone browsing the system what the deal is, and people catch on quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a JIRA plugin that makes component level versioning possible. It is suitable for the exact scenario you have described. In addition to component specific versions, you can also group different component version into a bundle. You can check plugin details from the [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.deniz.jira.versioning) or [plugin's help pages](http://jiraplugins.denizoguz.com/plugin-help/).

Comment: Deniz your pluging looks really good, its a pity you don't have a cloud version.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it, but due to restrictions of Cloud API it is not possible to implement Cloud version.